# News items stack in top of each other with CSS position

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm trying to create a webpage that has news items in a way that it has news image, image overlay, headline and text all in top of each other. However with my code, if I try to continue to create next news below copying everything, it will stack in top of the first news. So how can I get the next similar "News2" image+image+headline+text combo appear under the "News1" instead of overlapping?

I could use "top: xxx px;" to force News2 items down, but it seems like a bad solution when there will be lots of news items in a page.

HTML:

```
<div class="NewsImage1 NewsImageBig"><img src="image.jpg" class="NewsImageBig"></div>
<div class="NewsImageOverlay1 NewsImageBig"><img src="Gfx/imageoverlay.png" class="NewsImageBig"></div>
<div class="NewsImageHeadline1">News headline goes here</div>
<div class="NewsImageText1">News text goes here</div>
```

CSS:

```
.NewsImageBig {
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 850px;
    max-height: 283px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 0px 12px;
}
.News1 {
    position: relative;
}
.NewsImage1 {
    z-index: 0;
}   
.NewsImageOverlay1 {
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0.9;
}
.NewsImageHeadline1 {
    position: relative;
    top: 215px;
    margin: 0px 45px;
    font-size: 22px;
    z-index: 2;
}
.NewsImageText1 {
    position: relative;
    top: 220px;
    margin: 0px 45px;
    font-size: 14px;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

Example of webpage when there's only code mentioned here and when I try to duplicate the news item.

[image: Example]

Comment: You need to wrap the entire news element into a div that contains `position: relative`, otherwise your absolute attirbute will be taken relative to its parent (the body I guess here). The `absolute` property works in relation with the nearest `relative` element

Comment: best would be to not use position; absoltue and position relative in the first place but to use flexbox to align the content at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example about the `absolute` and `relative` relation. Here both .shadow and .title are `position: absolute`, only when set to a `position: relative` container it keeps the normal flow

```css
.news {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 40%;
  padding-bottom: 25%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

.news .shadow {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top:0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
}
.news .title {
  color: #FFF;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  bottom: 5%; left: 5%; right: 5%;
}
.news .title h2, .news .title p {
  margin: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
  <div class="news" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/200);">
    <div class="shadow"></div>
    <div class="title">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>lorem ipsum dolor sit emet</p>    
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="news" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/200);">
    <div class="shadow"></div>
    <div class="title">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>lorem ipsum dolor sit emet</p>    
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a perfect and much simpler solution to my website. Much obliged.